# I can't fix my bottom menu in any way on Chrome (while on FIrefox works perfectly)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm new to HTML/CSS3, so in order to strengthen the skills I've learned during an online course I'm trying to clone homepages of famous websites.

Now, I've almost completed the homepage of flickr.com but I've made a stupid mistake: I tested it only on Firefox (where it works smoothly on smartphone, tablet and desktop 1920*1080p view). Then I tried it on Chrome and...it was a disaster. My footer section was not working:

- in tablet and desktop view, there's a gap between the footer and the bottom of the page I can't fix;
- **but** although I can't fix the problem on my own, I managed to identify the problem: it's the little arrow near the word 'English' inside the footer (I need it cause when I click on it the language menu will pop up as in the original website). And I'm almost sure that this has to do with the 'position:absolute' propriety I assigned to that arrow in my style.css file (but I can't remove that property, otherwise it'll look ugly) ;
- I tried working on padding and margin in any way I could think about, but I can't solve the problem and I can't tell if it's just bad styling or if the problem is connected to bad framing in my index.html file.

I don't know if someone is willing to give a look to my work. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

index.html:

```
    <div class="header-container">
        <header>
            <a class="logo" href="#">
                <img class="flickr" src="images/flickr-logo-2435.svg" alt="#">
                <p>flickr</p>
            </a>

            <nav>
                <div class="search-box">
                    <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="search" id="searchbar"
                        placeholder="Photos, people or groups">
                    <a class="search-icon" href="#">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="nav-button-A">
                    <a href="#">Log In</a>
                </div>

                <div class="nav-button-B">
                    <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>


    <main>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Find your inspiration.</h1>
            <h2>Join the Flickr community, home to tens of billions of photos and 2 million groups.</h2>

            <div class="start-button">
                <a href="#">Start for free</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>



    <footer>
        <div class="footer-nav1">
            <div class="footer-button">About</div>
            <div class="footer-button">Jobs</div>
            <div class="footer-button">Blog</div>
            <div class="footer-button">Developers</div>
            <div class="footer-button">Guidelines</div>
            <div class="footer-button">Help</div>
            <div class="footer-button">Help forum</div>
            <div class="footer-button">English

                <img class="arrow" src="/images/pngegg.png" alt="line down">
                
                <div class="language-nav" style="display: none;">
                    <a class="language" href="#">Italiano</a>
                    <a class="language" href="#">French</a>
                    <a class="language" href="#">Espanol</a>
                    <a class="language" href="#">Deutsch</a>
                    <a class="language" href="#">日本語</a>
                    <a class="language" href="#">Portugues</a>
                    <a class="language" href="#">한국어</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="footer-nav2">
            <div class="footer-button">Privacy</div>
            <div class="footer-button">Terms</div>
            <div class="footer-button">Cookies</div>
            <div class="footer-button">
                <p>SmugMug+Flickr.</p>
                <p>Connecting people through photography.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="social-nav">
                <a class="social-button">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-square-facebook"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="social-button">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="social-button">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
html {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    animation: animate 20s ease-in-out infinite;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


@keyframes animate {

    0%,
    100% {
        background-image: url(images/0.jpg);
    }

    25% {
        background-image: url(images/1.jpg);
    }

    50% {
        background-image: url(images/4.jpg);
    }

    75% {
        background-image: url(images/3.jpg);
    }
}


/* GLOBAL MOBILE */
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.header-container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

header {
    background-color: rgba(53, 57, 57, 0.376);
    height: 65px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0px 20px 0 15px;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.flickr {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: white;
}


.search-box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    background: #2f364000;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}

.search-txt {
    border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ffffffbd;
    outline: none;
    color: #4e5052;
    font-size: 12px;
    transition: 0.1s;
    line-height: 34px;
    width: 0px;
}

.search-icon {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    background: #2f364000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.1s;
    text-decoration: none;
}



.search-box:hover>.search-txt {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 130px;
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
}


.search-box:hover>.search-icon {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #4e5052;
    background: #ffffffbd;
}


nav {
    display: flex;
}


a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-button-A,
.nav-button-B {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.nav-button-A {
    border: 2px solid white;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
}

.nav-button-B {
    /*show only in TABLET and DESKTOP mode*/
    display: none;
    margin-right: 15px;
    border: 1.5px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
}

.nav-button-B a {
    color: #000000;
}

.nav-button-B a:hover {
    color: #8b8c8d;
}

main {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

.wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*to reactivate in TABLET and DESKTOP mode*/
.wrapper h2 {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.56rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 30px 40px 50px 40px;
    line-height: 1.9rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper a {
    font-size: 1.45rem !important;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 17px 23px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.start-button {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.start-button a:hover {
    color: #8b8c8d;
}


footer {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
}

.footer-nav1 {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.footer-nav2 {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 10px 15px 10px;
}


.footer-button {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.734);
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.257);
}

.footer-button p {
    padding: 3px 0px;
    text-align: center;

}

.footer-button:hover {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.language-nav {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -240px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}



.language {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: white;
}

.language:first-child {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.language:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.language:hover {
    background-color: #e6eaec;
}


.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}

.arrow:hover>.language-nav {
    display: block;
}

.social-nav {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.social-button {
    color: #808080;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.social-button:hover {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
}



/* TABLET */
@media (min-width: 444px) {


    .logo {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }


    .search-box:hover>.search-txt {
        width: 420px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }


    .nav-button-B {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 7px 20px;
    }

    .nav-button-A {
        border: none;
        padding: 7px 15px 7px 5px;
    }


    main {
        height: calc(100vh - 110px);
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .wrapper {
        padding: 0 40px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .wrapper h2 {
        display: block;
    }

    .start-button {
        margin-top: 70px;
    }

    .wrapper a {
        font-size: 1.35rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 18px 30px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .footer {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 auto;
    }


    .footer-nav1 {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.257);
    }

    .footer-nav2 {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    }

    .footer-button {
        font-size: 0.85rem;
        border-bottom: none;
    }


    .footer-nav2>.footer-button {
        border-bottom: none;
        padding: 20px 15px;
    }


    .footer-button p {
        display: inline;
    }

    .language-nav {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline;
        margin-top: -265px;
        margin-left: -45px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
}




/* DESKTOP 1920x1080p */
@media (min-width: 1080px) {

    nav {
        width: 95%;
    }

    .search-box {
        justify-content: center;
        width: 85%;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    .search-txt {
        border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
        border: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
        background: #ffffffbd;
        outline: none;
        color: #4e5052;
        font-size: 12px;
        transition: 0.1s;
        line-height: 34px;
        width: 1400px;
    }


    .search-icon {
        display: none;
    }

    .search-box:hover>.search-txt {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 1400px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }


    main {
        /* background-color: beige; */
        height: calc(100vh - 60px);
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }


    .wrapper {
        padding: 0 600px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    .wrapper h2 {
        line-height: 2.1rem;
    }

    footer {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        min-height: 60px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 auto;
    }

    .footer-nav1 {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-grow: 2;
        border-bottom: none;
    }


    

    .footer-nav2 {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-grow: 1;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0 auto;
        margin-left: 25px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .footer-nav2>.footer-button p:last-of-type {
        display: none;
    }



    .footer-button {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .social-nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-grow: 1;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .social-button {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        color: #808080;
        padding: 0 auto;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    .footer-nav2>.footer-button {
        border-bottom: none;
        padding: 20px 37px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .social-nav {
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 300px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .social-button {
        color: #808080;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }


}
```

jquery-nav.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.arrow').on('click', function(){
        $('.language-nav').toggle();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were exactly right! It was that English word causing problems... well not really the English word, it was the div surrounding it.

You have to close that div, from this:

```
<div class="footer-button">English
```

To this:

```
<div class="footer-button">English</div>
```

Comment: Hi Miguel, thank you for taking the time to check my code and answer me. Unfortunately your solution doesn't work: it (aprtially) fix the problem with the gap, but it makes the little arrow go crazy. I actually closed that <div> tag after the <img> and the <language-nav> tags exactly to make sure to keep the little arrow near the 'English' word and to create there the wrapping language menu. I had already tried the solution you suggested, but while it partially solves a problem (in desktop view the gap is still there anyway), it creates another problem (the little arrow is misplaced now).

Comment: Btw I just wanted to tell you that I fixed it in the end. I actually had to work on the padding of my 'footer-button' <div>, but not only on that. I had to remove the 'position: absolute;' (which was the main problem) from the css style of the <img> tag. Also, I wrapped  the 'English' word inside a <p> tag and then I kept it wrapped inside the 'nav-button' <div> along with the <img> and the 'language-nav' <div>. Finally I worked with flexbox, padding and margin.